# New Components Which Implement Methods Not Already in an Interface

Tags: c#, design-patterns, interface

I have two class files (`WallSwitch` and `ProximitySwitch`) - let's assume they're third-party-supplied components - which implement the Methods `On()` and `Off()` from an `IUserController` interface which I have built in my core, consuming system.

I also have three classes - also third-party-supplied - namely, `CeilingFan`, `Lightbulb` and `CCTVCamera`, which implement Methods from an `ICeilingComponent` interface, which is part of the core system. These `ICeilingComponent`-implementing classes are instantiated and injected into the `IUserController` inheriting classes, for example:

```
ICeilingComponent component = new LightBulb();

IUserController controller = new WallSwitch(component);
```

Then...

```
controller.On();

controller.Off();
```

Everybody's happy.

I now have a new, third-party-supplied component called `DimmerSwitch`, which also implements the `IUserController` Methods of `On()` and `Off()`, but the `DimmerSwitch` class additionally implements the Methods `IncreasePower(int amount)` and `DecreasePower(int amount)`, which only affects the `CeilingFan` and (dimmable) `Lightbulb`, not the `CCTVCamera`.

I'd like to accommodate this in the core system, but I'm failing to understand how to do it without compelling the other third-party components to change their construction as described by the interface I've contracted them to implement. That's the important bit. There must be a way I can handle this within the core system without affecting change elsewhere.

What design pattern or Interface methodology have I failed to understand correctly?

I had hoped that writing this all down would somehow present a solution to me. But nope. Maybe I can’t see the wood for the trees right now. Have searched for what I thought would be the right terms. This must be a common problem, surely. Feel free to make me look dumb.

P.S. This clearly isn't a real-world problem - I certainly don't wish to encourage discussions about voltage. But this isn't homework either: I only wish I were that young. I'm just trying to get my head around this problem to facilitate my understanding. Any responses appreciated (except any about electrical charge).

Comment: What does `controller.On()` do? I mean, I know it is supposed to turn on the ceiling component, but what method of the `ICeilingComponent` interface does it call to accomplish that?

Comment: Hi @John Wu, in this case it's just an esoteric console program to help me get clear about the issue. There are no juicy implementation details. It just calls a 'public void On() {Console.WriteLine("Fan rotates");}' method from the subclass, for example. It returns a string to the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create an enhanced interface called, for example, IEnhancedUserControl, like this

```
interface IEnhancedUserController : IUserController
{
void IncreasePower(int amount);
void DecreasePower(int amount);
}
```

Then your CeilingFan and Lightbulb implement this enhanced interface rather than original interface. This way you can avoid change the rest code, like original interface, CCTVCamera, etc.

Comment: That's the ticket. I was convinced Interface inheritance wouldn't work since I'm injecting the components into the controllers' constructors and that would break the compatibility between the CCTVCamera (a base ICeilingComponent) and the new DimmerSwitch (an IEnhancedUserController expecting an IEnhancedCeilingComponent). However, an overloaded constructor in the DimmerSwitch took care of backwards compatibility. I have a slight concern overloaded constructors in this case break the Interface Segregation Principle, but that's potentially for another question. Thank you for your response.